# 2D numpy array of 0's and 1's - where cells are 1 set the surrounding 12x12 cells to 1 as well

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

have a large 2d numpy array, dimensions 1500x1500, which represents a maze. Cells contain 0 and 1, where 0 is open space and 1 is occupied. I want to account for dimensions of robot, so poss easy way to do this is amend the map so that where original cells are 1, set surrounding cells up to 3 cells away in any direction to 1.

Had a look at masks, convolution etc but not sure how to proceed, grateful for help.

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

becomes

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Edit: Simplified Q to 3x3 "mask" with example

Comment: Apologies I thought it was clear. If a cell in a 2d numpy array has value 1, I want to set all neighbours in a 12x12 "mask" to a value of 1. I'm not sure how else to phrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to find the locations of all the `ones` in the original `maze` and than change the values in the surrounding area `s` to `1` as well:

```py
import numpy as np
maze = (np.random.random((15, 15)) < 0.02).astype(int)
print(maze)
s = 3
idx = np.where(maze)

for i, j in zip(*idx):
    lowerleft = np.array([max(0, i-s), max(0, j-s)])
    topright = lowerleft + 2*s+1
    maze[lowerleft[0]:topright[0], lowerleft[1]:topright[1]] = 1

print(maze)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  generates "IndexError: too many indices for array" on maze[lowerleft[0]:topright[0], lowerleft[1]:topright[1]] = 1

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is called binary dilation and can be done simply with `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

output = binary_dilation(input, structure = np.ones((7,7)))
```

This also allows you to do things like lop off the corners (by tinkering with the `structure` array) if you want to exclude by Euclidean distances instead of Manhattan distances.

Comment: That is super elegant, just needing .astype(int)  to get output array back to binary 0 and 1's. Thanks!